# Find element with rel attribute and change text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pagination for browsing older posts. I need to change it's text using jquery or js. (pagination generated in laravel package so can't edit text directly)

So I tried with finding rel and replace text. But no luck. This is my code.

```js
$(".older-posts").find("li[rel='next']").html("Older posts");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="older-posts">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li>
      <a href="http://localhost/pages/blog?page=1" rel="prev">« Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled"><span>Next »</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your HTML has no `span[rel="next"]` element

Comment: you could use [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) `.find("span:contains('Next')")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pure js solution:

**Please Note**: querySelectorAll returns an array, so position of li matters; if u change position of "prev" li , then this code might behave naughty.

Cheers

```
document.querySelectorAll('[rel="prev"]')[0].innerHTML = "Older posts";
```

Approach 2:

If you feel that above code is incomplete for the reason I mentioned, use this approach instead

```
var lists = document.querySelectorAll("li")

var filteredList = Array.prototype.filter.call(lists,function(node) {   return node.innerHTML.includes("Previous"); });

filteredList[0].innerHTML = "Older posts";
```

Answer (score 1):

$('[rel="prev"]').text('your text here')